# Laravel + PhpStorm caching issue

Tags: laravel, caching, phpstorm

I have downloaded my project from the server to local exclude tests, storage and .cache directories.

When i going to change some blade files -> save+upload. I see no changes on my website.
I can see them after `artisan view:clear` command.

However, then I'm using FileZilla with notepad++ or even phpStorm **remoteHost** mode. I can see every changes at once on my website.

Can someone explain me this moment? How it's possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by removing option **Preserve files timestamps**.
I spent a huge amount of time on this! Hope it helps someone

Comment: thanks for sharing the solution. It sounds like this is caused by Laravel caching mechanisms. E.g. I can see it being used here: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-caching